# Area of a shaded region

Tags: geometry

[image]

What is the area of shaded region??

```
The radius of a circle is 4.

What I have tried :
if radius : r= 4 
then length of square : length=8 
and half of it is width of rectangle :width=4 So
```

[image]

```
The Area of a shaded region = area of rectangle(CDGF)-Areaof triangle(DGE)
=>legth*width-1/2(legth*width)
=>8*4-1/2(8*4)
=>24-12
=>12 

the area of shaded region is 12
```

but answer does not have this option !! it does carry the option "**None of these**" but I am confused with my answer !!!

Comment: But the side of the square is not $8$. The diagonal is.

Comment: then how to do ??@Ari if i consider BCD triangle than if square side is not 8 so the same Problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"None of these". Write $a=EF=EG=GD$, then you know $ED=4$. By Pythagoras, $EG^2+GD^2=ED^2$, i.e. $2a^2=16$; so $a^2=8$. The shaded area is $EF\cdot FC+\frac12 GD\cdot GE$, that is $\frac{3}{2}a^2=12$.

Answer (score 0):

You know it has to be "None of the above" because it is the only answer that doesn't include "$\pi$". The question tells you that half the diagonal of the square has length $4$, so its side length is $4\sqrt{2}$. The circle needn't be there at all.

Comment: I guess this is an IQ-type of question. It needs analysis like yours.

Comment: Yes u right @Edward Jiang this the practice question for my test !!